# Angular 2 testing - service won't inject

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I'm using angular 2 and jasmine to try and test a couple of services, one service is dependent on the other.  I keep getting a provider error for service.

```
import {Injectable}     from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

spec for serviceA

```
import {it, 
  describe, expect, 
  beforeEach, 
  beforeEachProviders, inject}
from 'angular2/testing';
import {ServiceA} from './serviceA;

describe('ServiceA Tests', () => {
  let service: ServiceA;

  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
        ServiceA
    ]
  });
  beforeEach(inject([ServiceA], (l) => {
    service = l;
  }));

  it('Service Created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

config class

```
import {OpaqueToken} from 'angular2/core';

export let APP_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken('app.config');

export interface Config {
  applicationBaseUrl: string;    
}

export const CONFIG: Config = {
  applicationBaseUrl: 'some value',
};
```

service b

```
import { Injectable,Inject}     from 'angular2/core';
import { Http,Response,RequestOptions,Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {APP_CONFIG, Config,CONFIG}    from './app.config';
import {ServiceA} from './serviceA';

export interface IServiceB {
}

@Injectable()
export class ServiceB implements IServiceB {
  constructor(private _http: Http,@Inject(APP_CONFIG)
       private _config:Config,private serviceA: ServiceA) {

  }

}
```

spec for service B

```
import {it, describe, expect, beforeEach, beforeEachProviders,
inject} from 'angular2/testing';
import {ServiceB} from './serviceB';
import {ServiceA} from './serviceA';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response, RequestOptions,
Headers}   from 'angular2/http';
import {APP_CONFIG, Config, CONFIG}    from './app.config';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';

import 'rxjs/Rx'; // Add all operators to Observable

describe('ServiceB Tests', () => {
  let serviceB: ServiceB;
  let appConfig: Config;
  let http: Http;
  let serviceA: ServiceA;
  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        provide(APP_CONFIG, { useValue: CONFIG }),
        ServiceA,
        ServiceB
    ]
  });
  beforeEach(inject([APP_CONFIG, Http, ServiceA,ServiceB], (ac, h, a,b) => {
    appConfig = ac;
    http = h;
    serviceA = a;
    service = b; // new ServiceB(http, appConfig, serviceA);
    appConfig.applicationBaseUrl = '/';

  }));

  it('Http created', () => {
    expect(http).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('service a created', () => {
    expect(serviceA).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('App config created', () => {
    expect(appConfig).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('service B created', () => {
    expect(serviceB).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

Service A loads and runs fine.  If I manually create ServiceB things work but if I try to inject ServiceB I get error.

> Failed: No provider for ServiceA! (ServiceB-> ServiceA)

It creates ServiceA so not sure why its saying no provider.

Answer (score 1):

I made a try with your code and it works for me regarding dependency injection with beta15. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZgCgNh?p=preview.

There was a small typo in the code of your test for ServiceB:

```
beforeEach(inject([APP_CONFIG, Http, ServiceA,ServiceB], (ac, h, a,b) => {
  appConfig = ac;
  http = h;
  serviceA = a;
  serviceB = b; // <-------------
  appConfig.applicationBaseUrl = '/';
}));
```

Could you tell me more about the environment you used? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2015,  angular beta 15, typescript 1.8.9, jasmine 2.4.1,  Your test looks correct but that's not what I get.  I can inject Service A into another service C but can't inject service B into Service C

Comment: Okay! Thanks. Same version as me in the plunkr? Would it be possible for you to share me something to reproduce (plunkr or github repository)?

Comment: I put my actual services in here https://plnkr.co/edit/ft7VJ8PMptJbyFdcc4RX?p=preview